# Javascript line under navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'm using little Javascript to allow me to have a line drawn under links in my website.

Here is the code :

```js
$("li").on("click", function() {
  $("li").removeClass("line");
  $(this).addClass("line");
});
```

```css
.line {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav justify-content-center">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="javascript:void(0)">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="javascript:void(0)">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So as you can see it simply add a line under the selected li. The problem is i've another list in my page and so it also add a line under those items and I don't want that.

How can i ask my Javascript to add a line under items ONLY from the nav class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind click handler to class `class="nav-item"` instead of `li` so it will only underline and click on a `li` with particular class name in your case 'nav-item`

```js
$(".nav-item").on("click", function() {
  $(".nav-item").removeClass("line");
  $(this).addClass("line");
});
```

```css
.line {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav justify-content-center">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="javascript:void(0)">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="javascript:void(0)">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ohh that's great :) happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

Make it more specific. So event will be triggered only when the click is target to a `li` with class `nav-item`.

If `nav-item` is also common between other `li` you cna add another class to the `li` on which events will be triggered.

```
$("li.nav-item").on("click", function(){
$("li.nav-item").removeClass("line");
$(this).addClass("line");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#line-container li").on("click", function(){
 $("#line-container li").removeClass("line");
 $(this).addClass("line");
});
```

```html
 <ul id="line-container" class="nav justify-content-center">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="javascript:void(0)">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="javascript:void(0)">Disabled</a>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

> You can add 'Id' around the ul (or class for that matter) that's used for showing up line and specify that
>
> using the id as above